# Does rain purify the earth in a similar way we use water for spiritual purification rituals or does the purification require a human element?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, water, kedusha-holiness, cleaning, environment

Judaism has different rituals around water and purification. A simple example is washing of the hands after a funeral or cemetery visitation.

My question is this.

Water is used for purification. Is the water itself innately purifying (it's a quality which Hashem gave water by default) or is water only purifying when it comes to our actions around the water itself?

***A Jew says a blessing and applies the water to a specific ritual purpose.***

If water is innately purifying by default and this quality doesn't require human intervention, would it be wrong for a person to assume that rainfall is purifying the environment (not just physically but spiritually) as one would assume when water is used for a Jewish ritual purpose?

**As a followup:**

Assuming rain does provide some level of purification, would it be beneficial for a Jew to visit a traditionally unclean place like a cemetery after rainfall if you believed it provided a level of purity to the location?